# Looking for a vectorized replacement of for loop for vector/matrix manipulations

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a nx2 matrix `M` and I want to subtract a vector `p` from each row of it. Like:

```
M(1,1)=M(1,1)-p(1); M(1,2)=M(1,2)-p(2);
M(2,1)=M(2,1)-p(1); M(2,2)=M(2,2)-p(2);
```

and so on

And then i want to collapse the modified `M` to a vector `N` of norms like

```
N(1)=norm(M(1,:));
N(2)=norm(M(2,:));
```

and so on

I can easily write a `for` loop to do this. Is there a vectorised way to do this instantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [bsxfun](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and calculate the norm manually:

```
% Subtract P
M = bsxfun(@minus, M, p);

% Calculate the norm
N = sum(M .^ 2, 2) .^ 0.5;
```